# How to combine more than one statement into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Alright, here is a little scoop of what I am trying to accomplish. I have a case statement in the select statement. Here is what I have...:

```
CASE pu.Group_Value 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'B' 
    WHEN 3 then 'C' 
    WHEN 4 then 'D' 
    WHEN 5 then 'E' 
    WHEN 6 then 'F' 
    WHEN 7 then 'G' 
END AS Groups,
```

The issue I am having is this case statement can have more than one return that comes back. What I need to do is be able to combine these into one. I end up having 7 rows coming back, but only need one row with all 7 letters in that rows column...

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you need to concatenate rows.  Are you using SQL Server or some other DBMS?

Comment: No it can't. The case statement will be evaluated per row. It doesn't generate new rows. Could you further explain, perhaps with examples of what your starting data looks like, the scenarios that lead to 7 rows coming back and the desired end state?

Comment: I have tried concatenating rows... SQL Server 2008R2...

Comment: Ok I can have all seven values comming back and what I do is I take these values (1,2,3,4,5,6 & 7) and assign them a letter. But not at all times do these come back (might only get 1 or 2). What I need to do is be able to combine the "WHEN" together so it would be like (A, B, C) and so on... Right now I will return only one row and that is what I need, but the column that needs these values only shows the one letter and populates more rows with the different letters...

Comment: Excellent, you are looking to `concatenate` these values together based on some grouping criteria (all rows with same ID go together). Does order matter? Is 1,2,3,4,5 the same to the consumer of the data as 5,4,3,2,1 and 1,3,5,4,2 ? Also, when you respond to comments, it's usually helpful to edit those into your question and then alert the questioner by using the @ handle

Comment: Yes @billinkc (sorry)! Order does kind of matter in this situation...

Comment: You can do it using `FOR XML PATH` like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FOR XML PATH`. For example:

```
SELECT STUFF(
  (
    SELECT ','+ CASE pu.Group_Value
                  WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
                  ...
                END 
    FROM pu
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,1,'') as Groups
```

Just make sure you don't leave any room in your CASE logic for NULLs or it will make the whole string NULL.

Comment: Could I get a little better example, was just a little confusing for me ...? @PinnyM

Comment: See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1211/12) to understand how this is built.  If you have a more complex query, please post and I'll show you how to use them with STUFF and FOR XML PATH

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is a GROUP BY pu.Group_Value.

The number of rows returned by this depend on the rest of the SQL query besides what you've included above.  If you only want to return one row, SELECT TOP 1 ... is your quickest bet, otherwise you will need to be much more specific with your WHERE clause criteria or evaluate using a GROUP BY, which might change what columns you include in your SELECT.